# Protools Midi help needed

Tags: pro-tools

I hope this isn't a silly question but is there a way of recording one of the internal instrumnents in Protools 8 (eg grand piano) onto an instrument track in a session without using a midi controller.

Comment: piano roll view. although that's editing it into place, not really recording it.

Comment: big question. how you plan on playing the virtual instrument?

Answer (score 2):

Not natively.

I've used v.m.k and it's been helpful:

http://www.fredrikolofsson.com/pages/code-apps.html

Allows you to use the computer keyboard as a controller.